# How to prove that second derivative of $\log\big(\int_{-\infty}^x e^{\frac{-t^2}2} dt\big)$ is $>-1$?

Tags: calculus, integration, statistics, definite-integrals

Let $\Phi(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x e^{\frac{-t^2}2} dt$.
How can I prove that
$$\left[\frac{e^{\frac{-x^2}2}}{\Phi(x)}\right]'>-1?$$

I could prove that its $lim$ at $-\infty$ is $-1$ and at $\infty$ it is $0$ but the l'Hospital rule did not seem to be enough to prove the inequality. At zero the value is $-\frac 2\pi$.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! This question is missing context or other details: Please 
improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes 
your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This 
information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them 
write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: I hope now it's better. I am really not sure what else could be added.

Comment: @johnny thanks, that looks good. It just helps us know what level your at, knowledge set etc., plus people like to know you have tried something before helping :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\phi(x)=e^\frac{-x^2}{2}$. Note that $\phi'(x)=-x\phi(x)$.

$$x\sqrt{x^2+4}+x^2+2>0\\
\iff x+\sqrt{x^2+4}>\frac{2}{\sqrt{x^2+4}}\\
\iff \frac{1}{2}\left(-x+\sqrt{x^2+4}\right)>-x+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+4}}\\
\iff 1>\frac{1}{2}\left(x+\sqrt{x^2+4}\right)\left(-x+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+4}}\right)\\
\iff \phi(x)>\frac{1}{2}\phi(x)\left(x+\sqrt{x^2+4}\right)\left(-x+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+4}}\right)\\
\overset{\text{integrating}}{\implies} \Phi(x)>\frac{1}{2}\phi(x)\left(x+\sqrt{x^2+4}\right)\\
\iff \left(\Phi(x)-\frac{1}{2}x\phi(x)\right)^2>\phi(x)^2(1+\frac{x^2}{4})\\
\implies x\phi(x)\Phi(x)+\phi(x)^2<\Phi(x)^2\\
\iff \left(\phi(x)/\Phi(x)\right)'>-1.$$